# Make it so 'Go/Enter' key is pressable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have a basic form which makes it so the user cannot leave the input field empty before the form posts the page. It also prevents the user from entering gibberish and requires them to only enter numbers, but this also blocks all keys that aren't numbers including the <kbd>Go</kbd>/<kbd>Enter</kbd> on mobile keyboards. My question is, is there a way to make it so that the user has to enter only numbers, but also be able to press <kbd>Go</kbd> after they have entered the field?

FIDDLE:http://jsfiddle.net/schermerb/nX8Hx/

Currently a user has to input a zip THEN tap back on the screen and THEN click submit.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#quantity").keypress(function (e) {
            if (e.which != 8 && e.which != 0 && (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57)) {
                $("#errmsg").html("Enter Valid Zip!").show().fadeOut("5000");
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    var initVal = "Have a good name for it? Enter Here";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");
        $(".recipe-name").blur(function () {
            if ($(this).val() != initVal && $(this).val() != "") {
                $(".submit-name").removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
                $(".submit-name").attr("disabled", "true");
            }
        });
    });
input {
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #acd50b;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 11px;
}
input[type="focus"] {
    outline: none;
}
input[type="submit"] {
    border-radius: 4px;
    border: 2px solid #2d8b1b;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    background: #acd50b;
    padding: 6px 10px;
    color: #444444;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.box {
    width: 85px;
}
.boxtwo {
    width: 160px;
}
<form action="google.html" method="get" id="recipename">
    <div class="box">
        <input onFocus="this.value=''" type="text" value="Enter Your Zip" placeholder="Enter Your Zip" /><span id="errmsg"></span>

    </div>
    <div class="boxtwo">
        <input type="submit" value="Compare" id="register" disabled value="Compare" class="submit-name" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: assuming ZIP codes are all the same length, then you could check the length of the inputted string and jump them out. If that's not a favorable option then you're going to need to look into the phone API's and figure out how the "go/next" button is made available.

Comment: Attached wrong fiddle, it's working now.

Comment: Nothing to do with the answer, but you should use `$().prop('disabled', true|false)` instead of `removeAttr("disabled")` and `attr("disabled", "true")`. For one thing, the correct value of the disabled attribute is "disabled", "", or nothing at all. For another, adding or removing attributes of an HTML element might not affect the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to use keydown and test the resulting value and revert it rather than only allowing certain characters to be inserted.

```
$("#quantity").keydown(function (e) {
    var self = this;
    var tempVal = this.value;
    setTimeout(function () {
        if (!isValidZip(self.value)) {
            self.value = tempVal;
        }
    }, 0);
});

function isValidZip(zip) {
    return /^[0-9]{1,5}$/.test(zip);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nX8Hx/3/

This could also be done with keyup or keypress, however keydown makes it happen much quicker and allows you to easily get the previous value.

Doing it this way avoids the issue of preventing the done key by not testing which key is pressed. It's also easily expandable by simply changing the regexp to match a different kind of zip code.